# Cómo interpretar los resultados del profiler en Netbeans 8.1

Tags: java, netbeans, profiler

He estado midiendo el tiempo de uso de CPU en una app de ejemplo con netbeans 8.1:

Medición del tiempo de uso de CPU por clases:
[image]

He leído la documentación del profiler y [he encontrado la diferencia entre CPU y Wall Clock Time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7335920/111110), y [también que "Total Time" y "CPU Time" del profiler son equivalentes a "wall clock time" y "CPU time"](http://wiki.netbeans.org/ProfilerMethods).
Pero en la documentación no pude encontrar información acerca del porcentaje en gris en las columnas Total Time y CPU Time: ¿es éste el porcentaje de uso de CPU por núcleo?

En esta imagen:
Telemetry:
[image]

El uso de CPU nunca alcanza el 100%. [¿El profiler de Netbeans mide el uso de CPU como VisualVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35952512/111110)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es el **tiempo relativo** de cada thread.

Por defecto, cada método agrupa todas las llamadas, incluso si fue llamado de diferentes thread (hilos). Y sí abrimos una rama, podemos ver como en el siguiente ejemplo:

[image: Profiler de la documentación con un método abierto en todos sus threads]

se muestra agrupado un mismo método llamado por diferentes threads, cada uno con un tiempo diferente. Es decir, se muestra qué porcentaje del tiempo total está asociado a ese thread (y obviamente suman 100% entre todos).

La barra roja a la izquierda y el número gris a la derecha muestran ambos este mismo valor: el tiempo relativo de cada thread sobre el método.

Comment: *facepalm* no se me ocurrió sumar los porcentajes de cada rama y ver si daban 100. Según el gráfico, los tiempos de pausa en relación al total son bastante largos.